# Ubuntu 18 - 511 C GPU temp and broken HDMI output

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Dell G7 with an NVidia 1060 GTX, bought in haste without thinking this through. I'm running Ubuntu 18, and just that (no Windows).

My temperature sensor is malfunctioning- nouveau/temp1(which I think is the GPU) reads 511 C (which is of course physically impossible). Googling a bit revealed that updating to the latest nvidia driver might fix this. However, whenever I do that (say with autoinstall), it breaks my HDMI output and I'm unable to use external monitors, even if I revert to the Xorg driver.

Could anyone please help me fix this?

Comment: There are many Nvidia driver version numbers. Which one did you try and what link did you follow for installation instructions?

Comment: 390, 410, 430 I think. I added the graphics-driver ppa and used auto-install. http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

Comment: I'm using driver 384 which also works with your GPU.

Comment: Tried it, same problem.

Comment: Oh sorry I just noticed you are looking at the wrong censor. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `nouveau/temp1` sensor only applies when you are using the nouveau driver. You are using the nvidia driver so you need to run:

```
$ nvidia-smi

Wed Jul 10 17:00:47 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   58C    P0    24W /  N/A |   1118MiB /  3016MiB |     18%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1383      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          1091MiB |
|    0     16007      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0     16056      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0     16222      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0     16233      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0     16254      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0     16517      G   compiz                                        11MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I never use this myself but rather have `conky` update information in real time on my desktop:

[image: conky nvidia.png]

Notice right hand corner 3rd line from the bottom reads a temperature of 58. The nvidia always runs hotter than the rest the system which in this case is 53.